# I'm getting a "Boolean Required" error in my Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I'm trying to get the Greater Than symbol to display when a result is 1000.

When going into Format Editor -> Common Tab -> then clicking on X+2 next to Suppress I then add the following line of code to display my result.

```
    if {tblcomplete.Num Res} >= 1000 then ">" + totext({tblcomplete.Num Res}, 0)
    else
    totext({tblcomplete.Num Res}, 0)
```

But I am receiving a "Boolean Required" error message when doing so.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that the Suppress exception MUST return a boolean.

To control what is displayed, use a formula -- not a suppress expression.